# I installed and ran Heritrix Web Crawler. It stored data in .arc.gz files

Tags: parsing, web-crawler

If you have used Heritrix Web Crawler, I'd really appreciate your help.

3 questions:

1. An arc file probably contains source codes of MANY pages in there.  How do I figure out which is which?
2. How do I interpret the .arc.gz files? I opened them in VIM and realized there were HTML code + junk (which I can't even parse using Python SGMLParser because of the junk).
3. Is it recommended to compress? (.gz)

Basically, I have no idea what .ARC files are and what I can do with them.
I'm used to using URLLIB2 to download and parse HTML manually.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Her's a link to download ArcReader, and an explanation: http://crawler.archive.org/articles/developer_manual/arcs.html.

I Googled for *reading arc files* and this was the first link.

First you need to unzip the files (they are gzipped, hence the .gz extension.). Then you can read the ARC file.